# Cannot find out why the same Excel VBA HTML code works for some entries and not for others

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a movie database in Excel using VBA and HTML coding (I'm a newbie on this area). My code is the following:

```
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim reqURL As String
Dim pelicula As String
Dim Contador As Long
Dim UltimaRow As Long
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim WolTiles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim WolTile As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Temporal As Variant
Dim QueSpace As Variant


UltimaRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Contador = 2 To UltimaRow
    pelicula = Trim(Range("A" & Contador).Value)
    reqURL = "https://www.filmaffinity.com/us/search.php?stext=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(pelicula)
    req.Open "GET", reqURL, False
    req.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = req.responseText
   
    '********* alternative 2
    If req.Status = 200 Then
        Set WolTile = HTMLDoc.getElementById("movie-rat-avg")
        If Not WolTile Is Nothing Then Range("B" & Contador).Value = WolTile.innerText
        Set WolTile = HTMLDoc.getElementById("movie-count-rat")
        If Not WolTile Is Nothing Then Range("C" & Contador).Value = Left(WolTile.innerText, InStr(1, WolTile.innerText, " ") - 1)
        Set WolTiles = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("movie-info")
        If WolTiles.Length = 0 Then
            Range("D" & Contador).Value = 0
        Else
            Temporal = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, "Year")
            Range("D" & Contador).Value = Mid(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal + 4, 4)
            Temporal = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, "Running time")
            QueSpace = InStr(1, Mid(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal + 13, 6), " ")
            Range("E" & Contador).Value = Mid(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal + 12, QueSpace)
        End If
        Set WolTiles = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("card-genres")
        If WolTiles.Length = 0 Then
            Range("F" & Contador).Value = 0
        Else
            Temporal = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, "|")
            QueSpace = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, ".")
            If Temporal > QueSpace Then
                If QueSpace > 0 Then
                    Range("F" & Contador).Value = Left(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, QueSpace - 1)
                End If
            Else
                If Temporal > 0 Then
                    Range("F" & Contador).Value = Left(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal - 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox req.Status & " - " & req.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

The excel file (lista.xlsm) has the following entries for testing purposes:

| title | rating | votes | year | Duration | genre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 Minutes of War | 5,5 | 923 | 2.019 | 98 | Drama |
| The Last Duel |  |  | 0 |  | 0 |
| Collateral Beauty | 5,9 | 9.196 | 2.016 | 94 |  |
| Da 5 Bloods | 5,3 | 3.143 | 2.020 | 154 | War |
| Daniel Isn't Real | 5,7 | 1.804 | 2.019 | 96 | Thriller |

As you can see "The Last Duel" entry does not show any data. But, if I compare the HTML output (saved to an external file after the line "HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = req.responseText" I can find the same Element Id's and Classes.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code as the 'The Last Duel' row is being processed?

Comment: Maybe because that search return a page with 2 entries `Duel: the Last Choice` and `The Last Duel`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a results list page, as more than one possible match, rather than a single film listing page.

You could check the content of the returned page to determine which type you have ended up on.

As the default ordering is by relevance, you might then assume the first film listing, on a results page, is the one to use, and thus make an additional request to get the film page for that listing.

Additionally, in future you may need to develop to handle no results.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutFilmInfo()

    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim reqURL As String
    Dim pelicula As String
    Dim Contador As Long
    Dim UltimaRow As Long
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim WolTiles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim WolTile As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim Temporal As Variant
    Dim QueSpace As Variant

    UltimaRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Contador = 2 To UltimaRow
        pelicula = Trim$(Range("A" & Contador).Value)
        reqURL = "https://www.filmaffinity.com/us/search.php?stext=" & Replace$(pelicula, Chr$(32), "+")
        req.Open "GET", reqURL, False
        req.send
    
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = req.responseText
   
        '********* alternative 2
        If req.Status = 200 Then
            
            If InStr(HTMLDoc.querySelector(".fb-sh").href, ".html&t=") = 0 Then 'on search results list page not specific film page
                 
                 reqURL = HTMLDoc.querySelector(".mc-title > a").href 'extract first listing as default sort is relevance
                 req.Open "GET", reqURL, False
                 req.send
                 HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = req.responseText
                 
            End If
            
            Set WolTile = HTMLDoc.getElementById("movie-rat-avg")
            If Not WolTile Is Nothing Then Range("B" & Contador).Value = WolTile.innerText
            Set WolTile = HTMLDoc.getElementById("movie-count-rat")
            If Not WolTile Is Nothing Then Range("C" & Contador).Value = Left(WolTile.innerText, InStr(1, WolTile.innerText, " ") - 1)
            
            Set WolTiles = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("movie-info")
            
            If WolTiles.Length = 0 Then
            
                Range("D" & Contador).Value = 0
            
            Else
            
                Temporal = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, "Year")
                Range("D" & Contador).Value = Mid(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal + 4, 4)
                Temporal = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, "Running time")
                QueSpace = InStr(1, Mid(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal + 13, 6), " ")
                Range("E" & Contador).Value = Mid(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal + 12, QueSpace)
            
            End If
            
            Set WolTiles = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("card-genres")
            
            If WolTiles.Length = 0 Then
                Range("F" & Contador).Value = 0
            Else
            
                Temporal = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, "|")
                QueSpace = InStr(1, WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, ".")
                
                If Temporal > QueSpace Then
                
                    If QueSpace > 0 Then
                        Range("F" & Contador).Value = Left(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, QueSpace - 1)
                    End If
                        
                Else
                
                    If Temporal > 0 Then
                        Range("F" & Contador).Value = Left(WolTiles.Item(0).innerText, Temporal - 1)
                    End If
                    
                End If
            End If
        Else
        
            MsgBox req.Status & " - " & req.statusText
            Exit Sub
            
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```